# Waiting custom time between stages

Tags: gitlab

I want the "verify" stage does not to start running after "test" stage is completed, I want the "verify" stage to start running X minutes after completion of the "test"  is completed.

```
stages:
  - configure-site
  - test
  - verify
```

Comment: Maybe add another stage in between that does nothing for X minutes? But why?

Comment: after pushing data into system in test stage, it should be wait X time to get data ready to be verified, because there is still some processing going on during X time.

Comment: Does that mean that when the "test" stage is done, it isn't actually done?

Comment: "test" stage is done properly, but during this stage some data pushed into system to be process internally, but it takes time to get data ready to get verified.

Comment: This needs to be represented by a stage that comes between "test" and "verify".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new stage in between the "test" and "verify" stage. That stage could simply execute a "sleep" command with the given time in seconds.

Otherwise, you could add the sleep-command to the end of your "test"-job.

Please be aware, that a job cannot run longer than 60 minutes per default ([docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#set-a-limit-for-how-long-jobs-can-run)).

```yaml
stages:
  - configure-site
  - test
  - wait
  - verify

configure-site:
  stage: configure-site
  ...

test:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - "configure-site"
  ...

wait:
  stage: wait
  needs:
    - "test"
  script:
    - sleep 600

verify:
  stage: verify
  needs:
    - "wait"
  ...
```

However, as the comments to your question already stated, I would tend to amend your jobs process to alert the CI when the publishing is finished, instead of just waiting for a specified time. I think, the "test" job should automatically wait until everything is *really* finished, instead of starting some process and returning some kind of success without knowing if the process really was successful.

Otherwise, maybe you could use the external status checks to ensure your publishing job is executed after the tests. Your external job could than call the API when the process is finished ([Gitlab collective article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/gitlab/articles/69193717/how-to-use-external-status-checks-for-merge-requests#heading-how-does-an-external-status-check-inform-gitlab-that-it-has-approved-the-merge-request)).